# Aligning two semicircles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm making `\item` commands with coloured circles. One needs to be two colours, i.e. two semicircles which form a single circle.

I currently have this, which superimposes both circles:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand*\reditem{\item[{\tikz[baseline=-3]{\node[shape=circle,draw,fill=red,inner sep=4pt] (char) {};}}]}
\newcommand*\redblueitem{\item[{\tikz[baseline=-3]{
  \node[shape=semicircle,rotate=90,fill=red,inner sep=3pt](char) {}; 
  \node[shape=semicircle,rotate=270,fill=blue,inner sep=3pt] (char) {};}
  }]}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \reditem test red
  \redblueitem test redblue
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I adjust this to form a nice two-colour circle?

Comment: Try adding `line width=0pt,anchor=south` to both nodes.  I had to guess what packages/tikz-libraries you're using, please consider adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I added dummy test code for a small beamer document. I had no idea there were different `tikz` libraries.

Comment: Does that compile for you?  For me, I get a complaint about the `semicircle` shape which is fixed by loading the `shapes.geometric` library (as in Jake's answer).

Comment: @AndrewStacey sorry about that, fixed and expanded.

Comment: No problem.  It just makes it easier to diagnose so although it wasn't an stumbling block this time then it's a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to both align them using their `south` anchors (which are located in the middle of the straight edge), and set the `line width=0pt` so there's no gap:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\redblueitem{\item[{\tikz[baseline=-3]{
  \node[shape=semicircle,rotate=90,fill=red,inner sep=3pt, anchor=south, outer sep=0pt](char) {}; 
  \node[shape=semicircle,rotate=270,fill=blue,inner sep=3pt, anchor=south, outer sep=0pt] (char) {};}
  }]}

  \begin{itemize}
  \redblueitem Test
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

---

A simpler way to achieve this might be to use `\path`s instead of nodes. Here's one approach in which I've defined a macro that contains the desired circle radius, so you can easily adjust the size of your circles:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\rubensradius{4pt}

\newcommand*\reditem{\item[{\tikz [baseline=-0.8*\rubensradius]{\path [fill=red, draw=blue] (0,0) circle [radius=\rubensradius-0.5\pgflinewidth];}}]}
\newcommand*\redblueitem{\item[{\tikz [baseline=-0.8*\rubensradius]{
    \path [fill=red] (0,\rubensradius) arc [start angle=90, delta angle=180, radius=\rubensradius];
    \path [fill=blue] (0,-\rubensradius) arc [start angle=270, delta angle=180, radius=\rubensradius];
}}]}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \reditem test red
  \redblueitem test redblue
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting that `line width=0pt` and `outer sep=0pt` have the same effect.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Not really, since `outer sep` is initially defined as `.5\pgflinewidth` `=)`

Comment: Great, thanks! This is really helpful. The only problem I have now is that the two semicircles are aligned differently than a single circle. I suppose this is easily fixable by setting the anchor point location 3pt to the right, but I have no idea how to tell `tikz` that.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Come to think of it, setting `line width=0pt` is the cleaner approach, though. If the user decides to draw a thick outline around the semicircles, there would be ugly artifacts if only `outer sep=0pt` is set.

Comment: @rubenvb The alignment is because there is a spurious space after the `\tikz{ ... }` command in the `\redblueitem` definition.

Comment: Incidentally, after messing around with the parameters to the `\node`s then I agree with Jake that paths are easier to ensure that they are the same size.

Comment: You sir, are the bomb! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `calc` tikzlibrary:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}


\newcommand*\redblueitem{\item[{\tikz[baseline=-3]{
\node[shape=semicircle,rotate=90,fill=red,inner sep=3pt] (char) {}; 
\node[shape=semicircle,rotate=270,fill=blue,inner sep=3pt] at ($(char)+(6pt,0)$) {};}
}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\redblueitem something
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

or you can work at the lowest level (PGF):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\RBitem{\item[{\tikz[baseline=-3]
\def\r{5pt}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\r}}
\pgfpatharc{90}{270}{\r}
\pgfsetfillcolor{red}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\r}}
\pgfpatharc{90}{-90}{\r}
\pgfsetfillcolor{blue}
\pgfusepath{fill};}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\RBitem something
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

with the "same" output:

[image]